# Lambda関数からRDS Proxyを使用してRDSのDBにアクセスするときに2回に1回関数がタイムアウトしてしまいます。

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

サーバレスのアプリケーションを構築中で、LambdaからRDS Proxyを経由してRDS（Aurora PostgraSQL）と通信する箇所の検証を行っています。
ハンズオンなどを参考に構築したのですが、2回に1回関数がタイムアウトしてしまうという症状に悩まされています。逆に2回に1回は想定通りにDBからデータを取り出したりインサートしたり出来ます。

ちなみにLambda関数はAurora DBやRDS Proxyを作成したサブネットと同じサブネット内に配置して双方のセキュリティグループの許可設定も行っています。

Lambda関数のランタイム：Node.js 16.x
Aurora PostgreSQLのバージョン：PostgreSQL13.6

Lambda関数のコードは以下の通りです。

```
const {Client} = require('/opt/node_modules/pg');

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  try{
    // client設定
    const client = new Client({
      host: '【RDS_PROXY_ENDPOINT】',
      port: 5432,
      user: 'postgres',
      database: 'postgres',
      password: '【DB_PASSWORD】',
    });
    
    // 接続
    await client.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.error('connection error', err.stack)
      }
    });
    
    // クエリ実行
    const res = await client.query('select * from TASK');
    console.log(res);
    await client.end();
    
    return {
      statusCode: 201,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        dbResponse: res.rows
      }),
    }
  }catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
```

エラー時のログを見てみるのですが、以下のようにタイムアウトになったという情報しか得られなくて手がかりがつかめずにいます。

```
START RequestId: f388ee0c-ab98-410e-a530-8ca7a29ae727 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: f388ee0c-ab98-410e-a530-8ca7a29ae727
REPORT RequestId: f388ee0c-ab98-410e-a530-8ca7a29ae727  Duration: 3005.41 ms    Billed Duration: 3000 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 65 MB  
2022-05-26T00:37:00.843Z f388ee0c-ab98-410e-a530-8ca7a29ae727 Task timed out after 3.01 seconds
```

以下は成功したときのログになります。

```
START RequestId: 68d2b7dc-85a1-4bf8-b4a7-997d9106f577 Version: $LATEST
2022-05-26T00:59:03.084Z    68d2b7dc-85a1-4bf8-b4a7-997d9106f577    INFO    Result {
  command: 'SELECT',
  rowCount: 8,
  oid: null,
  rows: [
    { id: 0, name: 'task1' },
    { id: 1, name: 'task2' },
    { id: 2, name: 'task3' },
  ],
  fields: [
    Field {
      name: 'id',
      tableID: 16415,
      columnID: 1,
      dataTypeID: 23,
      dataTypeSize: 4,
      dataTypeModifier: -1,
      format: 'text'
    },
    Field {
      name: 'name',
      tableID: 16415,
      columnID: 2,
      dataTypeID: 1043,
      dataTypeSize: -1,
      dataTypeModifier: 14,
      format: 'text'
    }
  ],
  _parsers: [ [Function: parseInteger], [Function: noParse] ],
  _types: TypeOverrides {
    _types: {
      getTypeParser: [Function: getTypeParser],
      setTypeParser: [Function: setTypeParser],
      arrayParser: [Object],
      builtins: [Object]
    },
    text: {},
    binary: {}
  },
  RowCtor: null,
  rowAsArray: false
}
END RequestId: 68d2b7dc-85a1-4bf8-b4a7-997d9106f577
REPORT RequestId: 68d2b7dc-85a1-4bf8-b4a7-997d9106f577  Duration: 219.23 ms Billed Duration: 220 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 16 MB
```

このような症状の場合原因としては何が考えられますか？

Comment: 成功したときの時間は何秒で完了していますか？

Comment: コメントいただきありがとうございます。
成功したときのログも追記しました。
成功したときは219ミリ秒で完了しています。